# Not able to run my jar file on Windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, executable, manifest

I have these files `board.class` and `x4.class` (x4.class has main() method).

To jar these files, I wrote

```
jar cf x4.jar *.class
```

and got a `x4.jar` file.

I copied this x4.jar file to my Desktop (on windows Vista) and double-clicked it. I am getting this error:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest
>   attribute from
>   `C:\Users\eSKay\Desktop\x4.jar`

What should I do to make this file run as a jar executable (without installing any software)?

---

**UPDATE:**
I used a manifest file to fix the problem. I have got the jar file I needeed and it is running fine if you do:

```
java -jar x4.jar
```

But, when I double click x4.jar nothing happens, I checked Task Manager and found that a javaw.exe is being started in the background, but it is not showing the output the original program was giving.

**What can the problem be?**

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I have the correct manifest file and I've run jars before on my old comp but for some reason I'm having trouble now on my new one (Running windows 7 64-bit). I've been able to run the jar file in the cmd but when I click it nothing happens. I have reintalled java with jdk and jre 6(uninstalled older version first) and established my paths. javac and java work fine in cmd. also in properties it says that it is being opened by 'Java(tm) platform SE binary'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a [manifest file](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Manifest+Specification) which contains the `Main-Class` attribute to [specify its entry point](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Then use the "m" flag in the jar command to specify it. For example, you might have a file called manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: x4
```

Note that you need to have an empty line at the end of the file, or the `jar` tool won't process it properly, ignoring the final line *silently*.

Then run:

```
jar cfm x4.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

To test it, run:

```
java -jar x4.jar
```

Comment: If you've specified the attribute correctly you won't get *exactly* that error. Please post the contents of your manifest file. Run "jar tvf x4.jar" to make sure that the jar file really contains the manifest - it'll be there as `meta-inf/MANIFEST.MF` IIRC.

Comment: @Jon earlier I did not create any manifest file. After you told me, I just copy pasted those two lines to my manifest.txt file. "jar tvf x4.jar" shows that the manifest file is present. a screenshot -  http://imgur.com/7YHAS.jpg . Its in front of me, somehow I am getting the "exactly same" error!!

Comment: Actually, I think you get a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file no matter what.  But if you use the "m" parameter, then you can *override* the default one.  So, @eSKay, can you try extracting the JAR file and making sure the manifest is the one you want?

Comment: @Matt you are right, i unjarred it and the Manifest file is not what i provided. What am I doing wrong? My manifest file (unjarred version) reads "Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)"

Comment: @eSKay -- Make sure you have a newline or carriage return following the Main-Class: x4 line. I knew @Jon was right, but wanted to see if there were any quirks. At 1st I was getting the same error. But then I remembered you needed a CR/LF. 

I found the following statement:
"Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return. "

here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Wayne's right - without the newline at the end, the Main-Class bit will be removed. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: I just checked, carriage return is also there. somehow, the manifest file that is being included in x4.jar is the default one, not the one I am providing.

Comment: And you're using exactly the command line I provided? I've just tried it and it was fine after I'd got the extra line terminator in there.

Comment: yes, i was missing the line terminator, it showed okay in Notepad++ but was not there when I opened the file through vi (using SSH to a linux machine). So I added it and now the error is gone. But, when I double click x4.jar nothing happens, I checked Task Manager and found that a javaw.exe is being started in the background, but it is not showing the output the original program was giving.

Comment: What happens when you run "java -jar x4.jar" from the command line?

Comment: @Jon it runs fine that way. what might the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Jon is correct, just make sure you end the file with a CR/LF.

[Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

> Warning: The text file must end with a
>   new line or carriage return. The last
>   line will not be parsed properly if it
>   does not end with a new line or
>   carriage return.

Or you can let the jar program automatically create the Main-Class attribute for you.

> The 'e' flag (for 'entrypoint'),
>   introduced in JDK 6, creates or
>   overrides the manifest's Main-Class
>   attribute. It can be used while
>   creating or updating a jar file. Use
>   it to specify the application entry
>   point without editing or creating the
>   manifest file. For example, this
>   command creates app.jar where the
>   Main-Class attribute value in the
>   manifest is set to MyApp:
>
> ```
> jar cfe app.jar MyApp MyApp.class
> ```
>
> You can directly invoke this
>   application by running the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> java -jar app.jar
> ```
>
> If the entrypoint class name is in a
>   package it may use a '.' (dot)
>   character as the delimiter. For
>   example, if Main.class is in a package
>   called foo the entry point can be
>   specified in the following ways:
>
> ```
> jar cfe Main.jar foo.Main foo/Main.class
> ```

Comment: (same comment as posted on Jon's post) yes, i was missing the line terminator, it showed okay in Notepad++ but was not there when I opened the file through vi (using SSH to a linux machine). So I added it and now the error is gone. But, when I double click x4.jar nothing happens, I checked Task Manager and found that a javaw.exe is being started in the background, but it is not showing the output the original program was giving.